# Execute class method PHP with parameters on the background

Tags: php, background, fat-free-framework

I have a class method that sends mails to many recipients, this method receive 2 parameters (one is an integer, and the other is a String), however, when this method is invoked from the main process, the timeout expires and the send no ends. Then, I need that this function (send) run in background, and I need to pass dynamically the parameters, so far i have tried with the `exec()` command.

I did read somewhere that I could pass the class and method name only putting a space in the command. Therefore, the command that I'm triyng is  `exec(/usr/bin/php /home/cesar/www/mails.php notices send 1 'Text' > /dev/null)`; however, this commando doesn't work, beacuse I don't receive the mails.

In this command:

- mail.php = file script php
- notices = Class name
- send = method name
- 1 = param1
- 'Text' = param2

Then, I have many questions:

1. What would the correct way to run this command in background?
2. How I could pass the parameters dynamically? Do I just do concatenate the command string with my variables?

By the way, this working with "Fat-Free Framework".

Thank you in advance,

Regads from Mexico,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to Omar's answer, I'm posting here two more solutions which are specific to the framework:

**Solution 1:**

Use the framework's [abort()](http://fatfreeframework.com/base#abort) method, to disconnect the HTTP client and continue sending mails in the background:

```
$f3->route('GET|POST /myroute',function($f3){
    echo 'Well done Callaghan!'; // message for the client
    $f3->abort(); // stop response here => the client can request something else
    // now we can run extra tasks in the background
    ini_set('max_execution_time',3600);// it may take some time
    $mail->send();
    $mail->send();
    $mail->send();
    ...

});
```

**Solution 2:**

Use the framework's [Cron](https://github.com/xfra35/f3-cron) plugin, to schedule background tasks:

```
$cron=Cron::instance();
$cron->set('MassMailing','Mass\Mailing->go','@hourly');
// Mass\Mailing->go will be executed every hour
```

You need a web hosting allowing [cron jobs](https://github.com/xfra35/f3-cron#step-1) to enable this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**exec** expects a string parameter, also you have to escape the text you send with **escapeshellarg** , so the whole command should looks like this to work :

```
 $text_to_send = "Hello World , "
 exec("/usr/bin/php /home/cesar/www/mails.php notices send 1 " . $text_to_send . " > /dev/null");
```

now in you **mail.php** you could recive the text like this :

```
$text_to_send = $argv[5];
```

also you have other alternatives to send emails in background other than this, for example you can store the text in database table and then you create  a cron job that work each let's say 1 minute that checks if there is any text to send in that table and then remove the text after sending it from the database.

other alternative is to use a libray to create background job for sending emails such as **php-resque** or **gearman**.